# Webview is not working in android

Tags: android

```
webview.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

In above code i am getting output sorry webpage not available error.

Comment: make sure you have the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> in the manifest

Comment: I guess he missing this

Answer (score 2):

Add `Internet` permission in your manifest .If not works let me inform

Answer (score 1):

Add Internet permission in your manifest file.